# How to call a newly added WCF method from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, silverlight

How to call the below `SaveData` method from xaml.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IDataForSilverlight
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<TableName> GetList();

        [OperationContract]
        void SaveData(int UserId, string FileName, byte File);
    }



 public class DataForSilverlight : IDataForSilverlight
    {
        public List<TableName> GetList()
        {
            int sess = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["User"]);
            DreamDataContext Data = new DreamDataContext();
            var TakeData = from s in Data.TableNames where s.To == sess select s;
            return TakeData.ToList();
        }

        public void SaveData(int UserId , string FileName, byte File)
        {
            using (DreamDataContext Data = new DreamDataContext())
            {
                TableName UserColum = Data.TableNames.Single(find => find.By == UserId);

                UserColum.Image = FileName;
                Data.TableNames.InsertOnSubmit(UserColum);
                Data.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
```

i am able to call GetList(); method like below

```
ServiceReference1.DataForSilverlightClient webservice = new DataForSilverlightClient(); 
webservice.GetListAsync();
```

but i am unable to call the 'SaveData' method in the same way.

Comment: Take a look at this walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621313.aspx

Comment: @Genelia D'Souza can you please provide the complete code. I mean the service code and the application code. so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time that you add/modify/remove methods AFTER the WebReference has been added/refreshed you need to **RIGH CLICK on the WebReference and select Update Web Reference**.

Comment: i am able to call GetList(); method like this ServiceReference1.DataForSilverlightClient webservice = new DataForSilverlightClient(); webservice.GetListAsync(); but i am unable to call the 'SaveData' method in the same way

Comment: If you add method AFTER you first created the WebReference you need to RIGH CLICK on the WebReference and select Update Web Reference. And you need to do this any time you change/add methods to the webservice